# CSV file not updating until script is terminated when continuously appending file

Tags: python, csv, raspberry-pi, export-to-csv, sensors

I recently started a project to make a data logging script for my Raspberry Pi. My goal is to make a program that can:

1. Collect voltage data from the pH sensor that's hooked up to my Pi (that's the `getData()` function).
2. Plot it on the screen in real time.
3. Continuously append them into a CSV file every few seconds.

I've included my code below for both the function that collects sensor data and the function that plots/saves them. Everything works as expected, except for some reason I can't see the new data added to the CSV file `test2.csv` until I terminate the code with Ctrl+C (the IDE is Thonny).

While the code is running, the csv file is just blank, and not even the heading "Data and Time, P0, P1" is there, making me think that for some reason Python doesn't actually append new data into the file until the very end.

If I stopped the script using the red "Stop/Restart Backend" button from Thonny, no new data will be added to `test2.csv`. New data will only be appended to `test2.csv` if I run the script ***and*** stop it using Ctrl+C, which isn't helpful because I want to be able to access the existing data without stopping the program.

Any idea on how to fix this so that the CSV file will update without me terminating the script?

My function for collecting data:

```
def getData():
    import board
    import busio
    i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)

    #import board module (ADS1115)
    import adafruit_ads1x15.ads1115 as ADS

    #import ADS1x15 library's version of AnalogIn
    from adafruit_ads1x15.analog_in import AnalogIn

    #create ADS object
    ads = ADS.ADS1115(i2c)
    ads.gain = 2/3

    #single ended mode read for pin 0 and 1
    chan = AnalogIn(ads, ADS.P0)
    chan1 = AnalogIn(ads, ADS.P1)
    return chan.voltage, chan1.voltage
```

Here is the part that actually plots and saves the data (and probably where things went wrong)

```
importing/initializing for plotting/saving
def DataLogger(file_name):
    #importing data from other function
    from getData import getData
    #importing/initializing for plotting/saving
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from time import sleep
    import csv
    plt.ion()
    voltage_list = []
    voltage1_list = []
    t = []
    ii = 0
    print("{:>5}\t{:>5}".format('P0','P1'))

    #create subplots and set axis
    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)
    fig.suptitle('Aquaponic Sensors')
    ax1.set_ylabel('pH (V)')
    ax1.set_ylim([2,4])
    ax2.set_ylabel('Temperature Voltage (V)')
    ax2.set_ylim([0,5])
    ax2.set_xlabel('Time (s)')

    #import date and time for timestamp
    from datetime import datetime

    #clear csv file on flash drive
    loc = "/media/pi/68D2-7E93/" + file_name
    f = open(loc, "w")
    f.truncate()
    f.close()

    #save data into test.csv on flash drive by appending new row
    with open(loc,'a+',newline='') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(["Date and Time","P0 (V)", "P1 (V)"])

        #define output of both channels
        while True:
            voltage = round(getData()[0], 3)
            voltage1 = round(getData()[1], 3)
            print("{:>5}\t{:>5}".format(voltage, voltage1)) #could remove
            #append new output to existing lists
            voltage_list.append(voltage)
            voltage1_list.append(voltage1)
            t.append(ii)
            ii = ii+1 #time counter
            sleep(1)
            #append data to csv file & plot
            if ii/5 == int(ii/5):
                now = datetime.now()
                dt_string = now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
                writer.writerow([dt_string, voltage, voltage1])

                #plot the lists
                ax1.plot(t, voltage_list, 'tab:blue')
                ax2.plot(t, voltage1_list, 'tab:red')
            #actually draws plot
                plt.draw()
                plt.pause(0.001) #some weird thing that makes the plot update, doesn't work without this pause
```

This is the file I used to run `DataLogger()`:

```
from DataLogger import DataLogger
DataLogger("test2.csv")
```

To run the file without any hardware connected, you can modify getData so it just generates random numbers and feed that into DataLogger

```
def getData():
    from random import seed
    from random import random
    seed(1)
    chanvoltage = random()
    chan1voltage = random()
    return chanvoltage, chan1voltage
```

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? The code that you provide is quite long and requires specific hardware to run.

Comment: Is `ii/5 == int(ii/5)` ever True? Just before the conditional add `print(ii/5 == int(ii/5))` - is it ever True? You might want to try `if ii % 5 == 0`.

Comment: First of all, you're mixing-up `f` and `file` in the `DataLogger()` function. After fixing that, then inside the function add a `file.flush()` call after every `writer.writerow()` to force the data to be written out to the CSV file being written.

Comment: @wwii I think ii/5 = int(ii/5) is true because without it, being true, nothing will ever get appended to the csv and the file wouldn't update at all, which is not the case here. It does trigger, and the graph does update in real time, it just doesn't append until the script ends.

Comment: @martineau What do you mean by mixing up f and file? File is just a string with the file name that the user can input in the main function, and f is how I was trying to open the file I think. Is one of them redundant? How would I replace f = open(file, "w"), f.truncate(), and f.close() with just file?

Comment: Well here's some examples: The `with open(file,'a+',newline='') as file:` which _replaces_ the initial value of `file` (which is initially a string) with the opened file itself (which is odd) and then below that there's a number of `f.close()` calls — there is an `f` file, but it was closed long before and there's no reason to keep doing it over and over. Also, if you open a file with `with`, you don't need to explicitly close it as that will happen automatically when the `with` clause is exited.

Comment: @Han-KwangNienhuys I added a way for you to run the code without hardware above (I think)

Comment: @martineau I changed the initial string "file" variable to "loc" and got rid of the f.close(), but everything still seems to run exactly the same? I updated the code above to what I have now. I didn't know that f.close() was unnecessary.

Comment: That's an improvement, but why do you keep calling `f.close()`? Plus, in addition to that, I also suggested that you call `file.flush()` after _every_ `writer.writerow()` to force the CSV data to be physically written out to the file (from the internal buffer that most files have). Doing things this way will would be more efficient that constantly opening and closing the file as @Nicholas is suggesting.

Comment: @martineau I did just that and it worked!!! I was actually under the impression that the file was f, so I was trying to close it to see if it updates. Turned out I had it wrong all along and the file was called file the whole time. Just out of curiosity: what's the difference between doing file.flush() and file.close()?

Comment: Bill: That's good to hear. `file.flush()` forces data in the file's internal buffer to be written out but leaves the file open for further usage. `close()` flushes it, too, but releases resources associated with it (like the buffer) which means that further I/O operations cannot be done with it (although obviously you can close one multiple times without an error occurring).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is actually pretty simple and easily reproducible. Python does not write to files until you close the file that was opened.

Proof:

```
with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
    file.write('1')
    input('Press enter to continue')
    file.close()
input('Press enter to continue')
with open(file_name, 'a+') as file:
    file.write('2')
    file.close()    
    input('Press enter to continue')
```

If you run this, and look at the file at all of the breaks you will find that the file
after the first break is empty, then becomes 1, then becomes 12.

In order to fix this, you should occasionally save the file by closing the opened file with `.close()` then reopening it.

## Edit:

There was an important correction to my answer by martineau. Adding here so that other viewers don't copy my mistake

> Python does write to files before they're closed. Files generally have an associated buffer in memory where data goes initially, and when that fills up it's actually written out to the physical file. When a file is closed, this happens before the buffer is full.

In order to clear this buffer, the `.flush()` function can be called, which will cause the buffer to write to the physical file.

Finally, in my example, I did open the file in append mode on the second call, instead of write mode, which changes the behavior from overwriting a file to appending data to the end.

Comment: By file do you mean the python script or the csv file? If you mean the python file, does that mean I am stuck using ctrl+C to terminate the script and rerunning it every once in a while? Is there no way to incorporate a saving functionality into the script?

Comment: I edited the answer to try to clarify, but I'll add it here as well. What you need to do is have your loop close the csv file every so often in order to actually commit the changes to the file you created. Until the file descriptor (the `file` variable in both your example and mine), is closed, all changes to the csv file are not actually added to the csv file. In addition, re-reading your example, you repeatedly close a variable `f`  which was only opened once. When you use the `with open(...) as foo` line, `foo` becomes the current file descriptor, which is the one I am saying you must close

Comment: I did as martineau suggested and added file.flush() after each append, and it updates now. I didn't realize that the file is actually called "file" after my "as..." assignment :/ Thanks for the help!

Comment: Nicholas: Python _does_ write to files before they're closed. Files generally have an associated buffer in memory where data goes initially, and when that fills up it's actually written out to the physical file. When a file is closed, this happens before the buffer is full. Regardless, in your answer I think you forgot to mention that you're opening the file in "append" mode all but the first time, which is an important detail IMO.

Comment: Oh thanks martineau! I was aware of this behavior for `print()`, but completely didn't realize this also applied to `open`. Doh. Thanks a lot! I've modified my answer to include your corrections.